# Add an image to a DataGridTemplateColumn header show System.Windows.Controls.Image

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I try to Add `Image` into `DataGridTemplateColumn header`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="IsSelected">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.ico" Height="25" Width="25"/>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

All ican see i  the `Column` header is `System.Windows.Controls.Image`

Answer (score 0):

It's the Data template you want to change:

```
    <DataGrid Height="100">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="60" SortMemberPath="IsSelected">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.ico" Height="25" Width="25"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCell>
            <DataGridCell.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding name}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </DataGridCell.Template>
        </DataGridCell>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What about my <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> ?

Comment: But I have several columns with check box that i want to add image and i want to image only in the header.

Comment: Then add several DataGridTemplateColumn into your Xaml... It will go under DataGrid.Columns